# How aggressive should one be with replacing aged steel pipes in a Norfolk VA brick house?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, brick, steel

I'm house-sitting my son's house that he just bought. It is at least middle aged and I'm concerned that it is a hidden cost. The exterior is red brick and the plumbing, as far as I can tell, is all steel pipe under the house and all behind brick walls.

I'm concerned that he has or will have a rusted through pipe under there and there is no way to get to it except removing the brick walls. Even if it isn't leaking, I'm sure the pipes are compromised and if one rusts through no one will know about it.

What should he do? Remove enough brick to get under the house and replace it all with PEX?

Comment: Wait until there is a problem but start saving now. Start reading up on the net and learn the options, steel was very common into the 70’s , my 1930 home has steel when I update a bath I don’t mess with the old stuff just plan to replace it if I was not remodeling I would be saving for a remodel.

Comment: @EdBeal  Can you point me to a source for more info? I guess I'm correct that one goes through the brick and under the house rather than through the hardwood floor?

Comment: If there is a crawl space it will be under the floor. Yes the pipes normally come up in the walls but internal walls are normally Sheetrock or plaster and really easy to replace plumbing. The best advice I could give you is to watch some shows on flipping houses, with the realization that they over dramatize just about everything. Brick homes are higher end they usually have crawl spaces if not they have gable or hip roofs , hot and cold supply’s can go low or high. The only home I won’t purchase is a flat roof with a  slab , there is a money pit , go on line watch some plumbing repair videos.

Comment: Awesome, @EdBeal, a major relief. Thanks.

Comment: If you touch any of it, be prepared to replace all of it. aka, *a can of worms*; try to open it only if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot offer a definite hard and fast rule regarding your situation, but if it helps, I can give advice based on my own experience. 
I live in South Africa, in Cape Town, on the coast, and recently bought a house of just over 100 years of age. 
In south Africa, even back then, we were using copper pipes, I've been doing alot of renovating over the last few years, and this is what I've realized in terms of ageing plumbing.

If its not completely necessary to replace, then don't do so, unless you're in a position to do so, there are definitely benefits to upgrading your pipes to Pex (Cobra-pipe in South Africa).

The very 1st thing I did, when re-doing the granny flat, was to bypass and block off the old system, and put in all new pipes all the way from the water inlet, through to geyser, through to all outlets. This was mostly because it was cheaper to do this, than deal with delays in hitting old pipes and halting work while trying to fix (The old pies were all over the show, so never knew where we'd hit another.
I've started doing the same in the main house, even though there we didn't actually need to upgrade.
The benefits I've found in redoing all the pipes are as follows: 
1) With PEX - Hot water from the geyser, was almost instantaneous, no waiting for the water to heat the pipes and eventually come out the tap at the required heat. - This translates into a saving of both water, and electricity - Imagine only running 1 or 2 liters of water through the hot water tap, instead of 10 Liters, every time you need hot hot water.
2)New pipes = no scale buildup. Often in old houses, there is quite a lot of scale build up, that can negatively affect the pressure.
3)Old houses here ran 15mm (internal diameter) copper pipes, and the system generally allowed 100 - 300Kpa of pressure (as that was what was supplied by the council back then. Nowadays, pressure valves, geysers etc, are usually 400 or 600 Kpa as standard in residential houses, with safety ratings of up to 2,000Kpa. The pipes these days are also bigger, 22mm, 28mm, and even 40mm. This allows for better pressure where you need it, showers, sprinkler systems, bathtubs etc (all these tiny differences save time) - filling a bath in 5 minutes, instead of 30 minutes etc.
4)Peace of mind - Knowing that you have put in a new system, that can last another 50 years and more, without issue makes a big difference to me. It also means I know where the pipes are, so I don't accidentally hit a pipe when drilling into a wall, or knocking through.
5)Value - Whether your son has bought the house to live in, or resell in a few years, the fact that the houses plumbing is new across the board will most certainly have a positive impact on the houses value.
6)Preventative maintenance - Just like replacing rubber pipes in your engine compartment while you have the top off (even those that don't need replacing), this is a similar situation, insofar as reactive maintenance is a lot more costly than proactive maintenance. With proactive, your in control of where you're going in, what and how you're replacing. With reactive, you're reacting to a leak / leaks so bad that they're already apparent on the insides of the walls, or floors, thus, it involves leak detecting - expensive hiring an inspection company. Having to dig / open up in possibly difficult places that will end up costing alot, fixing water damage to walls / floors / foundations - These are all costs that are out of your control. 
Not to say it will happen, but, if you're like me, I'd rather be in control of that 'chance'.

Comment: Excellent information @NedvahLotheringen . Thanks so much for taking the time to share your experience, et al. I will pass this on to my son.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the water , steel can last a very long time in some waters, so doing nothing unless there is a problem is an option. Find out from neighbors ( with steel pipe) if there have been problems. If any is accessible , a piece of pipe could be removed and examined  as an indication of the whole system but opening an old pipe connection can easily make problems. Pipe wall thicknesses are measured routinely in industry  with ultrasonics but it would be expensive to hire an inspection company.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in an other answer, (galvanized) steel pipes can be **very robust** - f.e. here in Europe the lines of the 60ies/70ies are made for a lifetime of minimum **100 years**. In those days, that was not a pure marketing parlance.
2. In domestic water lines, the galvanic series must be respected. In flow direction, the **nobility must never decrease**. F.e. copper can be installed downstream of steel, but never choose steel - copper - steel.
   In heating systems, this nobility rule is not important, if there is no leak that requires frequent topping up, since the water's oxygen is consumed after some time.
3. **Grounding** must be checked, if parts of the lines are replaced with plastic lines.
4. The calcium carbonate layers inside the pipe are **protecting the steel** surface. If the throughput gets too low, a careful mechanical removal can be tried. **Acids/chemicals must be avoided** under any circumstances.
5. Every house must have electric breakers. For water, there are **fusing systems**, that close the main incomer line in the event of too long or too much uninterrupted water flow or if the throughput is too high or at unusual time. Helps to get a good sleep, saves much time and money, since a preventive complete replacement of all lines is no more necessary. The new flexible lines between wall and faucet are not as reliable as the old metal lines, another reason to recommend those water fuses.
6. Plastic lines do get covered with a (normally harmless) **biofilm** in the inside surface, metal lines normally do not have those films.
7. Of course, **professional plumbers** may tend to recommend a full replacement of old lines.